# How to increment swap space in Solaris 11?

Tags: solaris

I keep getting to reboot (!) my Solaris V20 because of the swap being completely full. How can I add more space to it? I have allocated all the disk already.

Answer (score 2):

See *[Adjusting the Sizes of Your ZFS Swap and Dump Devices](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1448/ggrln.html#ggvlr)* in the Solaris 11 documentation on docs.oracle.com.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this tutorial](http://blog.deepreflect.net/2010/02/11/solaris-add-swap-to-zfs-disk/). It applies to Solaris 10, but it deals with adding swap space to a ZFS disk and should be valid for Solaris 11.

Comment: This doesn't apply to Solaris 11 which doesn't requires resizing any partition to extend the swap volume.

Comment: I'm afraid you are unlucky with that one. The tutorial you posted predates Solaris 11 and doesn't apply to it, i.e. you cannot create swap files on ZFS.

Comment: Thanks again, 1+ for guru-ism.